# maximum number of subarrays that contains both maximum and minimum elements of a resultant array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

You are given an array of n elements you allowed to delete at max one element from provided array. The order of elements remain the same .you are required to maximize the number of subarrays that contain both maximum and minimum element of the resultant array . A subarrays is the sequence of consecutive element of the array
Input
T no of test case
N size of array
N array element
Output
For each test case print one single integer the maximum number of subarrays that contains both maximum and minimum elements of the resultant array
Examples

4

6

7 2 5 4 3 1

7

1 2 3 4 5 6 7

6

2 5 3 2 5 5

4

5 5 5 5

Output

4

1

12

15

Test case 1 explanation
If we delete 1 from the array then the resultant array will be 7 2 5 4 3
So the number of subarrays will contains max 7 and minimum 2 will be 4

[7,2]

[7,2,5]

[7,2,5,4]

[7,2,5,4,3]

Comment: So you copy/pasted a challenge. Interesting. Any problem in solving it?

Answer (score 1):

Do some math. If the min and max elements are at the indices `i` and `j` (does not matter who is where, just `i < j`), the number of subarrays is `(i + 1) * (len - j)`. Prove this fact, or at least convince yourself that it is so.

Now, prove (or at least convince yourself) that it doesn't make sense to remove any element other than min or max.

I hope that this is enough to get you started.